# How to make desktop .exe of web application in Laravel or PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make desktop .exe of web application like laravel web application or php.

Answer (score 2):

Look into **PHP Desktop**
https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop

This project that was created to provide a way for developing native desktop GUI applications using web technologies such as PHP, HTML5, JavaScript and SQLite.

That said, Laravel is a web application framework, and is not optimized to be run as a desktop application out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider something like Electron:

https://electronjs.org

To name a few of the applications created with this wrapper:

- Slack
- Github desktop
- Atom editor
- Visual studio code

...and more.

Please note that this is just a wrapper for the frontend of your application. While you can still use Laravel as a backend API for your application you would still need to build the application itself as a separate javascript frontend.

If you are familiar with VueJS that ships with Laravel you should be able to use that framework for your Electron-frontend.

A couple of tutorials that might be interesting for this approach:

- https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-desktop-quiz-application-using-vue-js-and-electron
- https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Making desktop .exe of Laravel application is easy!

GitHub Repository: https://github.com/laravelarticle/laravel-desktop

1. Download the repository & extract.
2. Put your Laravel application into `www` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this : https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop
and then check Downloads section for more detail.

When you download this extract it on your wamp or xamp then put your code in www and check you can run your app by clicking on phpdesktop-chrome.exe its just simple.For more details you can ask any query.